# independence of basis for the canonical map from $\mathbb{C}$ into $V\otimes V^*$

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

let $V$ be a vector space. Is it true that the linear map $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow V\otimes V^*$ sending $1\rightarrow \sum_iv_i\otimes v'_i$ where $v_i$ is a basis for $V$ and $v'_i$ is the corresponding dual basis is independent of the basis chosen? I have read it somewhere and can't figure out why.

Comment: Yes, I've changed it now

Comment: Do you know the isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(V,V)\simeq V\otimes V^{*}$?

Comment: Yes I know the map but how does it give me that the sum above is independant of the basis chosen?

Comment: Ah okay I guess the maps $g_B:Hom(V,V)\rightarrow V\otimes V^*$ defined by a basis $B$ are all equal due to that they are the inverse of the corresponding map $f:V\otimes V^*\rightarrow Hom(V,V)$ and hence this map is independant of the basis chosen.

Comment: tip for things like this -- if you're feeling down-to-earth and not in the mood for abstraction, but you also don't want to write a bunch of symbols, you can always check: what happens to the isomorphism if I swap the order of two basis vectors, what happens if I scale a basis vector by a nonzero constant; what happens if I replace a basis vector by itself plus a multiple of another? If the map is unchanged after all three operations, then it's basis-independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Arnaud's hint.

Let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$, and let $\{v^1,\ldots,v^n\}$ be its dual basis. The following map is an isomorphism $$f:\begin{cases} V \otimes V^* \to \operatorname{End}_k(V)\\
 v\otimes \varphi  \mapsto (u \mapsto \varphi(u)v )\end{cases},$$
which sends $\sum v_i\otimes v^i$ to $u\mapsto \sum v^i(u)v_i = u$.

That is  $f(\sum v_i\otimes v^i)=\mathrm{id}_V$. By the injectivity of $f$, the sum $\sum v_i\otimes v^i$ is independent of the choice of the basis.